# Replacing strings with values from an array with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-replace

I'm trying to instruct [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to replace all the instances of given strings `flexes[i][0]` in my `files` into one of two values `flexes[i][1]` or `flexes[i][2]`.

**My setup**

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
replace = require('gulp-replace'),

files = {
    input: 'input/*.html',
    output: 'output/'
},

flexes = [
    [
        "Old 1",
        "New 1A",
        "New 1B"
    ],[
        "Old 2",
        "New 2A",
        "New 2B"
    ]
]
```

**My function**

For all the input files, function should replace for all *Old* with:

- *New A* if the passed mode argument is 1 or
- *New B* if the passed mode argument is 2

and save to output folder.

```
function repla(mode) {
    return gulp
        .src(files.test_htm)
        .pipe(
            flexes.forEach(
                element => replace(
                    element[0], 
                    element[mode]
                )
            )
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(files.test))
}

exports.prev = repla(1)
exports.prod = repla(2)

exports.default = repla(1)
```

**Error**

My solution produces an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:564:8)
    at repla (/gulpfile.js:39:10)
    at default (/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:439:12)
    at asyncRunner (/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: forEach returns undefined.  pipe is expecting a stream.

Answer (score 0):

`.pipe` expects a stream.  `.forEach` returns undefined, which is being passed to pipe as a parameter, which is why you are getting that error.
The way pipe works, is that you pass streams to `.pipe` for it to chain input and output through.  What you can do in this case is keep a reference to the gulp chain, and chain pipes on it with a loop:

```
function repla(mode) {
    var g = gulp
        .src(files.test_htm)

        flexes.forEach(
          element => g = g.pipe(replace(
            element[0], 
            element[mode]
          ))
        )

    return g.pipe(gulp.dest(files.test))
}
```

If you have a lot to replace and see performance problems, you can consider creating a concatenated regex using `|`.  You probably won't need it.

Comment: **Thanks! How do I pass the `mode` parameter into your solution?**

It works if I declare it globally on the top, with all the other ones as:  

    `const mode = 1`

but it generates AssertionError when I try to pass it directly through:  

    `const prev = gulp.series(repla(1), otherFunction); exports.prev = prev`

Comment: that's odd.  mode shouldn't affect that.  what version of gulp are you using?  gulp 4?  can you provide more context for the script?

Comment: `gulp.series( (cb)=>{repla(1);cb()}, otherFunction )`?  gulp.series should be expecting a string (name of a task) or function (callback function), not the gulp chain itself

Comment: Yes, I use Gulp 4.0.2. I isolated the function into its own, separate gulpfile.js to cut out the interference with other elements until I make `repla` work. The setup is just like **My setup** posted above. I replaced **My function** with yours and tried to make it work with direct `exports.prod = repla(2)` as well as `const prev = gulp.series(repla(2)); exports.prev = prev`. The only way I could make it work, was either through setting mode value in  **My setup** or by manually changing it from `element[mode]` to `element[2]`.

Comment: you want to be passing `(cb)=>{repla(1);cb()}` not repla(1).  series and parallel takes a function or string, but you're passing the gulp chain.  Was that working before with passing the gulp chain reference to series?  repla(1) returns gulp.src.pipe...'s return output, but series expects a function or string

Comment: `gulp.series( (cb)=>{repla(1);cb()}, otherFunction )` works like a charm. I'll try to integrate it with the rest of the tasks now. Thank you!

Comment: that's good.  so you shouldn't actually need to explicitly use the cb() callback, so ()=>repla(1) should also work.  note that gulp.src... returns a chainable stream, and the tasks that series and parallel takes are functions or named strings to other defined named tasks.  [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is another option to bind parameters to the repla function.  Most people don't like this approach though and tend to favor function closures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that doesn't require a for loop of any kind.  It uses `gulp-replace`'s ability to take a function:

```
  // this form of your replaces is much easier to work with
let flexes = {
  "Old 1": ["New 1A", "New 1B"],
  "Old 2": ["New 2A", "New 2B"]
};
 
function replaceStrings(mode) {

  return gulp.src(files.input)
    
    .pipe(replace(/Old 1|Old 2/g, function (match) {

      // console.log(flexes[match][mode]);    // e.g., "New 1A" 
      return flexes[match][mode];
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
};

exports.prev = gulp.series(() => replaceStrings(0));
exports.prod = gulp.series(() => replaceStrings(1));
```

This `exports.prev = gulp.series(() => replaceStrings(0));` is an easy way to pass an argument to a task function.

Call: `gulp prev` or `gulp prod`

This approach does require that you be able to craft a regex that matches all your strings to be replaced, as in `/Old 1|Old 2/g`.  That may not be possible for you, but it can simply be `/string1|string2|string3/g` or more complicated.  Obviously if you have a lot of those a `for..in` loop might be necessary (but I wouldn't use a `forEach` loop - search SO for problems with using `forEach` and `gulp` together).

The modified `flexes` data structure, allows for a really simple replace function:

`return flexes[match][mode];`

---

---

I personally think a better way to do this is with args in your command line.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const argv = yargs.argv;

function replaceStrings() {

  return gulp.src(files.input)
    
    .pipe(replace(/Old 1|Old 2/g, function (match) {

     //  console.log(argv.mode);  // 0 or 1
      return flexes[match][argv.mode];
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
};

exports.replace = gulp.series(replaceStrings);
```

Call: `gulp replace --mode=0` or `gulp replace --mode=1`