# Gulp - loop within pipe

Tags: arrays, gulp, str-replace

I'm using gulp-replace to modify static html.

The search and text values are stored in an array:

```
const stringReplace = require ( 'gulp-replace' );

const textValues = [
    [ 'global-app-title', 'My App Title' ],
    [ 'global-app-version', '01.01.00' ],
    [ 'global-comp-name', 'ABC Company, LLC' ],
    [ 'global-comp-name-logo', 'ABC' ],
    [ 'global-comp-brand', 'Marketing Solutions...' ],
etc...
];
```

**Basic Implementation (single element in array)**

gulp-replace works fine for a single index of textValues:

```
gulp.task ( 'update-html-custom:dist', function () {
    return gulp.src ( [ paths.src.custom.html + '/**/*.html' ] )

        .pipe ( stringReplace ( textValues[ 1 ][ 0 ], textValuess [ 1 ][ 1 ] ) )
        .pipe ( gulp.dest ( paths.dist.custom.html ) )
} );
```

**Loop thru Array**

I'm trying to modify the gulp .pipe command to loop thru each element in textValues. However, most of my html files will have multiple matches (of the same or different search strings), so I believe some kind of loop is needed within the gulp-replace pipe - I have to update all instances of a match before I hand off to gulp.dest.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725102/replacing-strings-with-values-from-an-array-with-gulp/62725657#62725657) suggested that gulp-replace can take a function, so I tried the following, but it errors out with 'TypeError: dest.on is not a function':

```
gulp.task ( 'update-html-custom:dist', function () {
    return gulp.src ( [ paths.src.custom.html + '/**/*.html' ] )
        .pipe ( textValues.map ( (item) =>{
            stringReplace( item[ 1 ][ 0 ], item [ 1 ][ 1 ] )
            }))
        .pipe ( gulp.dest ( paths.dist.custom.html ) )
} );
```

Is there a way to loop thru my array within a pipe command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

This may not be the tightest code, but it seems to work:

```
const gulpEach = require ( 'gulp-each' );

const textValues = [
    [ 'global-app-title', 'My App Title' ],
    [ 'global-app-version', '01.01.00' ],
    [ 'global-comp-name', 'ABC Company, LLC' ],
    [ 'global-comp-name-logo', 'ABC' ],
    [ 'global-comp-brand', 'Marketing Solutions...' ],
etc...
];


gulp.task ( 'update-html-custom:dist', function () {
    return gulp.src ( [ paths.src.custom.html + '/**/*.html' ] )
        .pipe ( gulpDebug ( {title: 'file name: '} ) )

        .pipe ( gulpEach ( function ( content, file, callback ) {
            let updatedContent = content;

            textValues.forEach ( ( item ) => {
                let textPos = updatedContent.search ( item[ 0 ] );

                while ( textPos >= 0 ) {
                    updatedContent = updatedContent.replace ( item[ 0 ], item[ 1 ] );
                    textPos = updatedContent.search ( item[ 0 ] );
                }
            } )
            callback ( null, updatedContent );
        } ) )

        .pipe ( gulp.dest ( paths.dist.custom.html ) )
        .pipe ( browserSync.reload ( { stream: true } ) )
} );
```

gulp-each hasn't been updated in a while, but it seems stable enough...